# Starting user journey from current journey in orchestration step Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm currently designing the User Journey using IEF. I have a scenario where I want to start another User Journey from the existing one - in one of the Orchestration steps if a certain condition is met. I don't want to repeat myself (by adding same steps again) as it is getting complicated. Is it possible to do? 
And secondly, is there any way to show a pop-up (with links in there) during any orchestration steps?

I have a user sign-up flow. in that flow during the path, if a certain condition is met, I want to bring the user back to Sign-in journey.

Thanks
Sanjay